# [Форма]льные метки

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

Обнаружил такие метки как [форма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0) и [формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b). По-моему в них нет особого смысла, вопросы то по вебу, то по GUI формам совершенно разных библиотек.

Предлагаю их выпилить или даже сжечь.

Comment: Эм.. Я бы web'овские формы оставил.

Comment: может для html-форм явно выделить [tag:html-form] ?

Comment: Поналетели сразу вебовики :) Специализированные метки, конечно, можно оставить.