# Давайте удалим [формы]?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, удаление-метки

Это совершенно безликие метка [формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b) и [form](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form) встречаются с самыми разными технологиями: Windows Forms (есть уже метка [winforms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms)), Google Forms (есть уже метка [google-forms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-forms)) и HTML формы (пока нет метки, но я создам).

Предлагаю сжечь эти метки и навесить везде вместо них специфические метки, указанные выше (для HTML-форм я создам метку [html-form](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-form)).

Comment: олсо https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5255/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Опять?? Ну уже было же!

Comment: Закрываем как дубликат?

Comment: @Nofate Короче можно метки выпиливать?

Comment: Всем кто ставит метку дубликата, прочтите подпись в причине закрытия - "Вопрос уже задавался ранее, **и на него уже есть ответ.**" ;-)

Comment: @Kromster это не повод создавать множество однотипных предложений.