Синонимизировать [формы]
Предлагаю синонимизировать следующие метки:

form (927 вопросов) описание есть
forms (167 вопросов) описания нет
форма (260 вопросов) описание есть
формы (95 вопросов) описание есть

Интересно, что у всех меток с описанием оно абсолютно одинаковое.
Основная - форма или формы, т. к. они на русском (какое число - множественное или единственное принято оставлять - не помню, а на мете не нашёл).

формы - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327

Жечь их надо: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5255/240512
